# How do I authenticate users in module structures in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I did a multiple authentication having admin and regular users differently. My challenge is `Auth::guard('admin_user')->user()->name` return null in every module in the application. How do I ensure the user credential persist in all my modules. I used the videos here for multiple Auth https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKRs7NICuwc&t=60s

Comment: You have maintained separate folder structures for admin module?

Comment: Yes I did. I have the modules folder within the app folder. The modules works fine except the user credentials and I also noticed it will not accept any session variable as it all returned null.

Comment: Are you having separate route file for admin?

Comment: yes, I created a separate route for admin. In fact, a different auth folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your routes around the "web" middleware.

Like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', function() {
   // Your Routes
});
```